# Switching between HTTP and HTTPS with SSL-Ext and Struts 1.2.9

Tags: ssl, struts

I'm using the sslext extension for Struts to enable/disable passing data over HTTPS. I've implemented it so that https is only used for credit card processing. Its working fine when switching to https but I cannot get it to switch back to http.

I've tried hitting another action where I've specified the following:

```
 <set-property property="secure" value="false"/>
```

I've also added the following to the jsp's:

```
 <sslext:pageScheme secure="false"/>
```

But I still seem unable to switch back to HTTP.

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
 gearoid.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by making sure that `mapping.findForward(...)` redirects to an action which wasn't ssl secured.
It's useless making a JSP page scheme unsecure, it only means that if set to true, ssl ext links the jsp page on secure channel.